# Chrome object doesn't update after new permissions acquired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a piece of code that requests a new permission for my chrome extension. The new permission I try to get is `nativeMessaging`. I get my popup where chrome asks to grant the new permission, now here is where the trouble begins.

According to `chrome.permissions.getAll` and `chrome.permissions.contains` I have the permission I requested. But when I check `chrome.runtime`, for example `connectNative` doesn't show up.

Also when I try to get the permission manually on the extension background page, I get the popup, according to `getAll` and `contains` I have the permission but still I get the error, that `connectNative` is not available.

As a workaround for now I just reload the extension with `chrome.runtime.reload()` and it works. but I would like to have it without release.

Is there a case, where the chrome object is not updated after you acquired new permissions?

Answer (score 0):

found out what happened. after you accessed chrome.runtime once, it is no longer possible to update it.

here is an example to trigger the problem:

bg.js:

```
chrome.runtime;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: ['nativeMessaging'],
  }, granted => {
    console.log(chrome);
    const type = typeof chrome.runtime.connectNative;
    alert((type === 'function' ? 'GOOD' : 'BAD') + ': ' + type);
  });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Native Messaging Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {},
  "optional_permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

comment the line 'chrome.runtime;' and it works again.